# Naming list elements in R based on applied functions

Tags: r, sapply

I have a set of functions `funs <- c(mean, median, min, max, quantile)` which I want to apply to a numeric vector `values`. This can easily done with `sapply()` but with its result none of the elements has a name. I want each list element named based on the applied function. I tried:

```
funs <- c(mean, median, min, max, quantile)
some_vals <- c(rnorm(14))

stats <- sapply(funs, function(fun) {
    result <- fun(some_vals)
    names(result) <- deparse(substitute(fun))
    return(result)
    }
)
```

But with that every list element is named X[[i]].
How can I name the list elements according to the applied function(s)?

Comment: Existing names are propagated by `sapply()`/`lapply()`, so you can name your function list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difficulty is that once you store the functions objects inside a list, they no longer *have* a name unless you specify a name for that object in the list.

I would use strings for the function names then `match.fun` inside `sapply`. This is easy to do and you get the names for free.

```r
funs <- c("mean", "median", "min", "max", "quantile")
some_vals <- c(rnorm(14))

sapply(funs, function(fun) match.fun(fun)(some_vals))
#> $mean
#> [1] -0.06134755
#> 
#> $median
#> [1] -0.3473996
#> 
#> $min
#> [1] -2.140686
#> 
#> $max
#> [1] 1.940046
#> 
#> $quantile
#>         0%        25%        50%        75%       100% 
#> -2.1406864 -0.7488198 -0.3473996  0.7707063  1.9400459
```

The alternative is to name your list:

```r
funs <- c(mean = mean, median = median, min = min, max = max, 
          quantile = quantile)

sapply(funs, function(fun) fun(some_vals))
#> $mean
#> [1] -0.06134755
#> 
#> $median
#> [1] -0.3473996
#> 
#> $min
#> [1] -2.140686
#> 
#> $max
#> [1] 1.940046
#> 
#> $quantile
#>         0%        25%        50%        75%       100% 
#> -2.1406864 -0.7488198 -0.3473996  0.7707063  1.9400459
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Can I provide extra arguments, such as the 'probs' argument, to the functions in the 'funs' vector when applying them?

Comment: The `funs` vector is a list of _functions_. Passing arguments to them is what you do when you _call_ them. If you want to pass extra arguments, your options are to define your own function with the arguments you want: e.g. `my_quantile <- function(x) quantile(x, probs = seq(0, 1, 0.1))` or to conditionally pass the argument inside `sapply`, e.g. `sapply(funs, function(x) if(x == "quantile") quantile(some_vals, seq(0, 1, 0.1)) else match.fun(x)(some_vals))`